# Can't clear pending transaction with current nonce getting an rpc error

Tags: ethers.js, json-rpc, pending-transactions, fees

Somehow my transaction was sent with extremely low gas fees from ETH mainnet to zkSync bridge. Is stays forever on pending

I saw this and tried to cancel it/speed it up but it did not work.

I tried to send a transaction with the same nonce and much higher gas limit and gas fees. Pending tx fee is 0.07$ so i tried to send a transaction with the same nonce with fee 8$. I did this from my metamask .... But everytime I get this error:

Failed transaction.
Transaction 1 failed [ethjs-query]while formating outputs from rpc '{value: {code:-32000,"message","transaction

What can i do to cancel this transaction?

Comment: Metamask handles this pretty well
Did you try via Metamask?

Answer (score 0):

When I run into this problem, I send a transaction with nonce=0. The next transaction works perfectly,

Hope it helps in your case!